# jQuery post method failing in iOS with Phonegap 1.7

Tags: jquery, post, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've written an app using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile. It's working great in Android, but I'm now trying to do it for iOS. Using XCode 4.3.3 with iOS 5.1, Phonegap 1.7, jQuery 1.7.1, jqQuery Mobile 1.1. The first part in the app is a logon. My javascript waits for the `deviceready` event and then makes a post to a PHP page to check logon credentials.

I've placed a bunch of alerts and the js fires fine until the post method, at which point it dies. First time through I got the whitelist exception error, so I added an entry to my ExternHosts in the Cordova.plist. Now when it hits post, I don't get any errors or anything.  Here's my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/login1.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="loginPage" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
  <h1>Sign In</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
  <form id="loginForm">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
  </form>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
  <h4>Stone Creek Portal</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-WebInspector.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
</html>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
function init() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, false);
  delete init;
}
function deviceReady() {
  $("#loginForm").on("submit",function(e) {
    $('#loginForm').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    $("#submitButton",this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    var u = $("#username", this).val();
    var p = $("#password", this).val();
    if(u != '' && p!= '') {
      navigator.notification.alert("before the post");
      $.post("http://someurl.php", {username:u,password:p}, function(res) {
        if(res.result != 'false'){
          var userID = res.result;
          localStorage.setItem('userID',userID);
          $.mobile.changePage("projectList.html");
        } else {
          navigator.notification.alert("Your login failed", function() {});
        }
        $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
      },"json");
    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

I'm really not sure what's stopping me. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this your full HTML? Shouldn't there be a phonegap.js include in there somewhere?

Comment: Are there some cross-domain problems?

Comment: The phonegap is there, it's the cordova-1.7.0.js.  I don't believe cross domain is a problem, from my understanding phonegap takes care of any CORS issues.